# Get percentage based on counts

Tags: postgresql, carto, mysql

I have the following query which gives me two columns `store` and `customer_count`...one row per store.

```
SELECT a.id AS store,count(b.*) AS customer_count FROM stores a, customers b 
WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom::geography,b.geom::geography,5000) GROUP BY a.id
```

This works perfectly.

What I need to add to this is another variable that represents the percentage of customers for each store. That is, `customer_count/total number of rows in customer table`. I'm just not sure how to structure this.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH sub_count AS (
  SELECT count(*) as total_cust from customers
  )

SELECT 
  a.id AS store,
  count(b.*), 
  count(b.*)::numeric/sub_count.total_cust AS customer_count 
FROM 
 stores a,
 customers b, 
 sub_count 
WHERE 
 ST_DWithin(a.the_geom::geography,b.the_geom::geography,5000) 
GROUP BY a.id, sub_count.total_cust
```